# Recover files from previous filesystem

Tags: data-recovery

Accidentally, I installed a new linux distro over a 100G partition of a 250G SSD, with my previous linux. I used it (system upgrades, web browsing) for around 30 minutes before I realised what I did.

It happened around 2019-02-26 22:15:00 -> 22:40:00. I am also interested in a specific directory, my previous home (/home/user). I am not searching for a specific file but everything I can recover.

Afterwards, I dumped the partition to an image. To be sure, I did it with 2 tools: dd and ddrescue. Also, to work with one of this two images (data-recovery process), I have copied it again. The partition is unmounted.

I started with ext4magic, but with no luck. I don't know if I am wrong, but it seems it needs the filesystem where we are trying to recover files. In my case, I cannot recover the previous filesystem.

Some info:

```
Filesystem in use: /mnt/data/rescue.wip/ddrescue_f_n_sda4.img

Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          ccb8bdf8-659b-4ad6-84b3-4fd918aee5e6
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              6553600
Block count:              26214400
Reserved block count:     1310720
Free blocks:              23951139
Free inodes:              6317540
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Tue Feb 26 22:20:43 2019
Last mount time:          Tue Feb 26 22:31:47 2019
Last write time:          Tue Feb 26 22:31:47 2019
Mount count:              2
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue Feb 26 22:20:45 2019
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          10 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      5b295e79-85ff-4af7-bef2-e42d1c48dbf8
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0x0bb27e03


Filesystem in use: /mnt/data/rescue.wip/ddrescue_f_n_sda4.img

|-----------c_time  Histogram-----------------  after  --------------------  Tue Feb 26 10:34:29 2019
1551177962 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 11:46:02 2019
1551182255 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 12:57:35 2019
1551186548 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 14:09:08 2019
1551190841 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 15:20:41 2019
1551195134 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 16:32:14 2019
1551199427 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 17:43:47 2019
1551203720 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 18:55:20 2019
1551208013 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 20:06:53 2019
1551212306 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 21:18:26 2019
1551216599 :   204037 |**************************************************|   Tue Feb 26 22:29:59 2019


|-----------d_time  Histogram-----------------  after  --------------------  Tue Feb 26 10:34:29 2019
1551177962 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 11:46:02 2019
1551182255 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 12:57:35 2019
1551186548 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 14:09:08 2019
1551190841 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 15:20:41 2019
1551195134 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 16:32:14 2019
1551199427 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 17:43:47 2019
1551203720 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 18:55:20 2019
1551208013 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 20:06:53 2019
1551212306 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 21:18:26 2019
1551216599 :      914 |**************************************************|   Tue Feb 26 22:29:59 2019


|-----------cr_time Histogram-----------------  after  --------------------  Tue Feb 26 10:34:29 2019
1551177962 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 11:46:02 2019
1551182255 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 12:57:35 2019
1551186548 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 14:09:08 2019
1551190841 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 15:20:41 2019
1551195134 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 16:32:14 2019
1551199427 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 17:43:47 2019
1551203720 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 18:55:20 2019
1551208013 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 20:06:53 2019
1551212306 :        0 |                                                  |   Tue Feb 26 21:18:26 2019
1551216599 :   206292 |**************************************************|   Tue Feb 26 22:29:59 2019
ext4magic : EXIT_SUCCESS
Filesystem in use: /mnt/data/rescue.wip/ddrescue_f_n_sda4.img

Using  internal Journal at Inode 8
Activ Time after  : Tue Feb 26 10:34:29 2019
Activ Time before : Tue Feb 26 22:30:00 2019
Error: Inode not found for "/home/user"
Check the valid PATHNAME "/home/user" and the BEFORE option "Tue Feb 26 22:30:00 2019
"
ext4magic : EXIT_SUCCESS
```

As you can see, it cannot find the pathname "/home/user", mainly because the current filesystem does not have a "/home/user". So, it seems it is not searching in the previous filesystem. I also tried with different datetimes around 22:30.

I am not centered in ext4magic, but I started with it. I read about other tools: extundelete, testdisk or photorec.

**What would be the best approach to recover every dir/file that existed before overwritting the partition (eg. at 2019-02-26 21:00:00) under the directory /home/user? Any recommedation?**

I have tried photorec a few times before, but it is a huge mess to detect and re-organise those thousands-to-millions of files because they don't preserve location/path/name. In case this is the only solution, what would you recommend to "semi-automatic re-organisation"?

Comment: Can you confirm that photorec finds your old files at all and not just new ones? You have SSD storage and `mke2fs` unfortunately does discard/TRIM by default, so usually all old data is gone and there is no way to recover anything. That's unless mkfs was run with `-E nodiscard` or the filesystem is on top of LUKS without allow-discard or the new partition was smaller than the old filesystem...

Comment: Effectively, I tried photorec using the whole ext4 image and it just found files from the new system. Panic.